# DAO Recordset with SQL Statement to Add Records with For Next Loop

Tags: sql, ms-access, for-loop, dao, recordset

I know this is silly, but I can't figure this out.  The Current Code below inserts the recordset meeting the criteria in TxtBox1, then erases the data in the Table by re-writing over them for the new recordset meeting the criteria for TxtBox2.

What I need is for the recordset meeting criteria in TxtBox1 to be inserted into the Table, then the next iteration of the recordset to be added to the Table when looped. (not writing over / deleting the first recordset return)

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim rrow As Integer, strCmboNmbr As Integer
Dim start As Object

Set db = CurrentDb()

strCmboNmbr = (Left(Forms("Match Summary").Controls("CmbNum").Value, 1))

For rrow = 1 To strCmboNmbr 'lets say 2
  Set start = Forms("Match Summary").Controls("TxtBox" & rrow) 'TxtBox1, TxtBox2, etc.
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT [Oracle JE].* INTO Unmatched FROM [Oracle JE] WHERE [Oracle JE].[Account Code]=" & start 'This is a MAKE Table Query
Next rrow
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to overwrite the table you'll need an append after the first run-through:

```
If rrow = 1 then
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT [Oracle JE].* INTO Unmatched FROM [Oracle JE] 
    WHERE [Oracle JE].[Account Code]=" & start 
Else
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Unmatched SELECT [Oracle JE].* FROM [Oracle JE] 
    WHERE [Oracle JE].[Account Code]=" & start 
End
```

Ideally, you'd have a table predefined.  Then you can add a primary key and index to it, clear it out first then run a series of appends.

Comment: Thanxs. I will create a predefined Table Structure with the required fields, add a primary key, index it, and clear it prior to performing this step...just as you suggested.  Thanxs, again.